# ngrx effects with rxjs websocket subject

Tags: angular, websocket, ngrx

I'm using websockets to communicate with multiple clients, that are using a ngrx store

What I'm having problems getting to grips with, is returning data (the payload) back into the effects via the websocket, so all users' stores can be updated.

I can log the payload in a service created to handle the websocket.

socket.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from '../../../node_modules/rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
  socket$ = Observable.webSocket( 'ws://localhost:8081');
  socketMessage$:Observable<any>;
  // 'ws://echo.websocket.org/'
  constructor() {
      this.connectToSocket()
   }

  connectToSocket(){
   this.socket$.subscribe(
      (message:Observable<any>) => {
        this.socketMessage$ = message;
       console.log(message)//this get broadcast to all users
      },
      (err) => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('complete')
    );
  }


}
```

The effects updates the blog, by first sending the action as the payload to the socket,

it should receive the payload from the socket, but does not and then go on to update the database via a service and finally creagte a new action "CrudSucessAction":

```
 @Effect() updateBlog$: Observable<any> = this.actions$
      .ofType<fromBlogActions.BlogUpdatedAction>(fromBlogActions.BLOG_UPDATED_ACTION)
        .mergeMap(action =>  {
            this.socketService.socket$.next(JSON.stringify(action))
            console.log(this.socketService.socketMessage$)//This only logs in the console of whomever made changes
        return this.blogService.updateBlog(action.payload.blog,action.payload.index)
        })
        .map((action)=>new fromBlogUIActions.CrudSucessAction(action))
```